# FIXED Trying fix broken code on reversing an array

Tags: c++, arrays

So I got this code sample that needs fixing. From what I can gather it takes an array, reverses it and then counts all the elements within it. Here is the code.

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
void ReverseTheArray( const short *pArrayStart, const int nArrayByteLength )
{

    const short *pArrayEnd = (pArrayStart + nArrayByteLength);

    while(pArrayStart != pArrayEnd)
    {
        short tmp = *pArrayStart;
        *pArrayStart = *pArrayEnd;
        *pArrayEnd = tmp;

        pArrayStart++;
        pArrayEnd--;
    }
}


//-------------------------------------------------------------------
int CountTheArrayContents( const short *pArrayStart, int nNumEntries )
{
    assert(nNumEntries-- > 0);

    int nCount = 0;
    for(unsigned uArrayIndex = nNumEntries; uArrayIndex >= 0; uArrayIndex--)
    {
        nCount += pArrayStart[uArrayIndex];
    }

    return nCount;
}

const short g_nSomeNumbers[] =
{
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
};

//-------------------------------------------------------------------
int main()
{
    short *pDataArray = new short[10];
    memcpy(pDataArray, g_nSomeNumbers, sizeof(g_nSomeNumbers));

    ReverseTheArray(pDataArray, 10*sizeof(short));
    int nCount = CountTheArrayContents(pDataArray, 10);

    printf("Sum total is %0.02f\n", nCount);

    return 0;
}
```

I have ideas of what the problems are but can't seem to figure out a simple solution to the problem, one that doesn't require rewriting the entire code. If anyone can read this and see how the errors can be fixed it would be much appreciated.

I'm going to mention some things that I think are causing problems.

All the parameters and the pArrayEnd variable in the ReversTheArray() function are all const but are trying to be changed within the while loop, which is throwing an error. Should the const's be removed? Is there a reason const's would be used for this?

If the const's are remove a runtime error happens when trying to run the for loop in the CountTheArrayContents() function expressing an unhandled exception and saying "Access violation reading location 0x003DFFFE". Drawing a complete blank on that one.

Again any help on the code would be very much appreciated and I couldn't thank you guys enough.

PS. This is a challenge to create a reverse and accumulate function so I'm looking for a fix for the code and not a removal of the two functions. Thank you

PSS. Thanks to everyone who answered. I'm glad I did this (this being the first problem that I've posted about myself) and you've all been a huge help. I've got to say I've learnt alot.

Comment: The "ByteLength" moniker is questionable in this, as the pointer math you're doing suggests it is `short`s, not *bytes*. Is that supposed to be a count of *elements* (not bytes) ? That you're also `memcpy`'ing **11** elements into an allocation only **10** elements wide isn't going to help your cause either. (its UB).

Comment: This doesn't even compile, you're attempting to modify `const` values in `ReverseTheArray`.

Comment: So you're reinventing `std::reverse` and `std::accumulate`.

Comment: As a bonus, the improper length passing not withstanding (assuming it is fixed to be element-count rather than bytes), an even number of elements will introduce yet more undefined behavior, as the start and end pointers will *never* equal each other. They will, in fact, *pass* each other as one moves up and the other down. Eventually, they will walk off the respective opposite ends and read/write to memory locations not part of the originating sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the actual length in bytes will add too many because pointer arithmetic is defined in terms of units of the size of the type pointed to. That is, `pArrayEnd` becomes `&pDataArray[10 * sizeof(short)]` instead of `&pDataArray[10]`. You don't need to multiply by `sizeof(short)` when calling the reversal function. Alternatively, you can divide `nArrayByteLength` by `sizeof(short)` when calculating the initial value of `pArrayEnd`.

The second issue is the fact that you only have 10 elements (0..9) allocated, meaning `&pDataArray[10]` would be one element beyond the array. The reversal function then tries to assign data to this unallocated area of memory, which can cause problems. The function should initialize `pArrayEnd` as shown, but immediately after, it should decrement `pArrayEnd` by 1. This way you won't be assigning to memory that might not belong to you. Beware of `pArrayStart == pArrayEnd` before you decrement `pArrayEnd`. An alternative test would be to ensure `nArrayByteLength != 0`.

Another problem is if the array has an even number of elements, and you try to do a reversal. If it does have an even number (like 10), `pArrayStart` will point to `pDataArray[4]`, `pArrayEnd` will point to `pDataArray[5]`, and after the data is assigned, `pArrayStart++` will make `pArrayStart` point to `pDataArray[5]` and `pArrayEnd--` point to `pDataArray[4]`. Then (6,3), (7,2), (8,1), (9,0), ... In other words, `pArrayStart` will never be equal to `pArrayEnd` in such a case. Instead, you should ensure that `pArrayStart < pArrayEnd`.

Hope this helps!

Also, any reason for not using `std:: reverse`? Just wondering.

**Edit**

The accumulation function can be rewritten as the following, which will avoid the issue with the `assert` macro while doing the same thing:

```
int CountTheArrayContents( const short *pArrayStart, int nNumEntries )
{
    int count = 0;

    assert(nNumEntries);

    while (nNumEntries--)
        count += pArrayStart[nNumEntries];

    return count;
}
```

Hopefully `count` doesn't overflow.

Comment: Adding to this, `assert(nNumEntries-- > 0);` will *ignore* the passed expression (it will not be evaluated *at all*) in a release build. This means a release-build will not evaluate `nNumEntries--`, which the code that follows relies on, and thus will introduce even more undefined behavior.

Comment: And (hopefully) the last hit in a long line, the format specifier `%0.02f` used in the final print does not match the data type being sent. The format requests a `double` or `float` (the latter promoted to `double` because its var-arg), yet the data passed is `int`.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested, I also took out the const's so that it would compile, still getting the Access violation exception at runtime, it is stopping in the CountTheArrayContents function

Comment: @TheHoester if you took to heart the things covered here, the code would look [something like this](http://ideone.com/d1rh7Q).

Comment: Thanks for this, really helped alot, it's all fixed and working now. WhozCraig, you nailed the last problem, just changed it to an 'i' instead, works perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

If all you're trying to do is reverse the contents of the array and accumulate the result, `std::reverse` and `std::accumulate` will do the trick (per the suggestion by @chris).  Here's an example, which maintains the dynamically allocated `short*`.  A better solution would use `std::vector` or `std::array`.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>

const short g_nSomeNumbers[] =
{
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
};

int main()
{
    short *pDataArray = new short[10];
    memcpy(pDataArray, g_nSomeNumbers, sizeof(g_nSomeNumbers));

    std::reverse(pDataArray, pDataArray+10);
    int nCount = std::accumulate(pDataArray, pDataArray+10, 0);

    for( size_t i=0; i<10; ++i )
        printf("%d ", pDataArray[i]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Sum total is %d\n", nCount);

    delete [] pDataArray;

    return 0;
}
```

This prints

```
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 
Sum total is 45
```

Comment: You know that `memcpy` is exceeding the boundaries of the dynamic allocation made on the line immediately preceding it, right? The global array is 11 elements wide, not 10.

Comment: Thanks for the help but this is a challenge to write a reverse and accumulate function from scratch. Fixing this code rather than changing it is what I'm looking for